# How do I access a resource with multiple endpoints with Flask-Restful?

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

Here's a simple Flask-Restful resource:

```
class ListStuff(Resource):
    def get(self):
       stuff = SomeFunctionToFetchStuff()
       if re.match('/api/', request.path):
           return {'stuff': stuff}
       return make_response("{}".format(stuff), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})

api.add_resource(ListStuff, '/list', '/api/list', endpoint='list')
```

My idea is to allow users to call both `/list` and `/api/list`.  If they use the first URL, they will get back an HTML representation of the data.  If they use the second URL, they will get a JSON representation.

My trouble is when I want to access the URL of this endpoint elsewhere in the program.  I can't just use `url_for('list')`, because that will always return `/list` , no matter whether the user accessed `http://host.example.com/list` or `http://host.example.com/api/list`

So how can I build the URL for `/api/list` ?

Comment: You have to add another resource for '/api/list'

Comment: e.g api.add_resource(ListStuff, '/list') & api.add_resource(ListStuff, '/api/list')

Comment: Hassan, thanks for the idea, but doesn't that do the same thing as what I've already got with `api.add_resource(ListStuff, '/list', '/api/list', endpoint='list')` ?  In either case, how would I build the URL for `/api/list` ?

Comment: Hmm yes you are right.  Then the best option will be to create another class for 'api/list'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like Hassan was on the right track - I can add a new resource for the same class but give it a different endpoint.

```
api.add_resource(ListStuff, '/list', endpoint='list')
api.add_resource(ListStuff, '/api/list', endpoint='api-list')

>>> print('URL for "list" is "{}"'.format(url_for('list'))
>>> print('URL for "api-list" is "{}"'.format(url_for('api-list'))

URL for "list" is "/list"
URL for "api-list" is "/api/list"
```